# Dataset for place for the drone landing place

Tags: machine-learning

Good morning. I am trying to build machine learning project which will be recognizing a drone landing place (stairs to home or doormat)

I need a dataset of like images but I do not know how to process them.

Comment: what kind of images do you require in your dataset? contact me, i can provide you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look for a dataset in the google dataset search:

https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/